# Word order in “出去了几个人。”

Tags: word-order

“出去了几个人。”这句话是从汉语规范词典：

> 出去
>
> chūqù
>
> 动 从里面到外面, 离开说话人所在的位置
>
> 出去买菜 | 他出去了 | **出去了几个人。**
>
> 注意 “去”口语中有时读轻声。

但是对我来说不太清楚。“出去了几个人。”跟“几个人出去了。”，意思一样吗？

I think “几个人出去了。” could be translated by “a few people [left]/[went outside]”. But I'm not at all sure about the meaning of “出去了几个人。”

It's just some basic vocabulary, but I feel like maybe I'm missing something important here... Help!

Comment: Yes, 出去了幾個人 (*the number of people who went out is how many?*) is the same as 幾個人出去了 (*how many people went out?*).

Comment: @droooze, you're saying it's an interrogative sentence. But I thought it wasn't, because in the dictionary they put “。” at the end, not “？”. So I thought it was a declarative statement. Could it be a declarative sentence?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. They're equivalent if a question mark is put on the end. In isolation, it just means *several people (幾個人) went outside (出去了)*, noting that the phrase order is reverse of that in English. An English translation in the same word order would produce something like *that which went outside was several people*, but of course this is an unnatural way to put it.

Comment: similarly 来了一个人，出现了新问题，三个人中死了两个才能保守住秘密 are examples of VS word order, see   e.g. http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Y05-1033 Sentences with VS word order do exist.

Comment: @droooze, is there any difference between the two declarative sentences 1. "出去了几个人。" and 2. "几个出去了人。"? As I understand it, both mean "several people went outside"

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler `出去了幾個人。` is ambiguous in written Chinese, while not ambiguous in spoken Chinese due to the intonation and rhythm. `幾個出去了人。` is grammatically incorrect - the closest sentence you'd get is `幾個出去了「的」人。` which means *the few people that went out*.

Comment: @droooze sorry, it's a typo. I meant: 1. "出去了几个人。" and 2. "几个人出去了。". (SE won't let me edit the comment any more.) Also, I would be interested in how intonation and rhythm are used to differentiate "出去了几个人。" and "出去了几个人？".

Comment: This is not something easily describable in written form - but less stress and slightly more rapid speech for 幾個人 compared with 出去了 means `出去了幾個人。` The opposite is true for `出去了幾個人？` - especially if「幾」is stressed. For intonation, questions naturally rise in intonation towards the end.

Comment: @droooze thanks. Still one question however.  is there any difference between the two declarative sentences 1. "出去了几个人。" and 2. "几个人出去了。". Is the meaning of these two 句话 the same?

Comment: Yes, they are, if spoken with the right intonation and stress.

Answer (score 1):

出去了几个人 is just a bit ambiguous. Are you making a statement or asking a question?

1. 出去了几个人?  How many people went out?
2. 出去了几个人 .  A few people left.
3. 他们几个人出去了。 They went out together.
4. 他们出去了几个人？How many of them went out?

Comment: In spoken language, what changes are made (stresses, pauses, ...) to distinguish between 1. and 2. ?